# Should 'FOR system_time ALL' include rows where the start and end times are equal?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

Querying a system-versioned temporal table with `FOR system_time ALL` appears to omit rows where the start and end times are equal.

For example:

```
/* Create a simple system-versioned table */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[svt_test](
    [string] [VARCHAR](30) NOT NULL,
    [validFrom] [DATETIME2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [validTo]   [DATETIME2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_svt_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [string] ASC
),
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([validFrom], [validTo])
) 
WITH
(
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[svt_test_history] )
);

/* 
Insert and immediately delete a row. 
May have to try multiple times to get a row with the same start and end    
timestamp. 
*/
INSERT INTO dbo.svt_test (string) VALUES ('string'); 
DELETE dbo.svt_test WHERE string = 'string';

/* 0 rows */
SELECT * FROM dbo.svt_test;
/* 1 row */
SELECT * FROM dbo.svt_test_history;
/* 
0 rows. 
Should be the "union of rows that belong to the current and the history table" 
  per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx 
*/
SELECT * FROM dbo.svt_test FOR system_time ALL;

/* 
   CONTAINED IN does not find the row either, even though MSDN says the    
   interval is defined as SysStartTime >= start_date_time AND SysEndTime <=   
   end_date_time
*/
DECLARE @Start DATETIME2(7);
SELECT @Start = validFrom FROM [dbo].[svt_test_history] WHERE string = 'string';
DECLARE @End DATETIME2(7);
SELECT @End = validTo FROM [dbo].[svt_test_history] WHERE string = 'string';
SELECT * FROM dbo.svt_test FOR system_time CONTAINED IN (@Start, @End);

/* Clean up */
ALTER TABLE dbo.svt_test SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
DROP TABLE dbo.svt_test;
DROP TABLE dbo.svt_test_history;
```

I've verified this on 2016 SP1 CU1 (12.0.4416) and 2016 CU3 (13.0.2186). I got the same result with `datetime2(0)` instead of `datetime2(7)`.

Would anyone happen to know whether this is likely a bug or by design? Alternatively, perhaps I've misunderstood something?

Comment: There might be some answers [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3682/sql-server-2016-tsql-syntax-to-query-temporal-tables/) but to me, logically, it could make sense that a row that was valid for exactly 0 microseconds "never existed"? In reality, there was no point in time where the values in that row were valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce what you see. Probably because I have a slow computer. But on the other hand it seems that the SQL Server developers have built this with my slow computer in mind and not your fast one.

If I wrapped the insert and delete in a transaction they got the same start and end timestamp every time.

From [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx)

> FOR SYSTEM_TIME filters out rows that have period of validity with
>   zero duration (SysStartTime = SysEndTime). Those rows will be
>   generated if you perform multiple updates on the same primary key
>   within the same transaction. In that case, temporal querying surfaces
>   only row versions before the transactions and ones that became actual
>   after the transactions. If you need to include those rows in the
>   analysis, query the history table directly.

So, if start and end timestamp are the same they assume it happened in the same transaction.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that note somehow! I get the same behaviour with second precision (`datetime2(0)`) instead of microsecond, so it seems unlikely to me that a developer didn’t account for a computer being fast enough to insert & remove a record at the same microsecond.